# How to avoid loss of driver object?

Tags: watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

i am trying to migrate our test automation from watir-classic to watir-webdriver. (Ruby 2.0, watir-webdriver 0.9.1)
Which is working fine in general, but our login process gives me a headache.

Lets me short explain what happens:

- Open Website A
- Enter login credentials and press login button.
- Website B is opened with the actual content while Website A is closed.

With the closing of Website A, the driver is also lost, i currently i cannot make a new instance of the driver to connect to the Website B.

when i try to do create an instance of the following pageobject, i get :

> variable name="@exception"  kind="instance" value="Unable to get
>   browser" type="Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError"

I do this by:

```
  def click_loginbtn
    @@driver.button(id: 'loginBtn').click
    return ProjectList.new(@@driver)
  end
```

Has anyone a good idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your driver is still active, you just need to access the new window.

To get a list of active windows available:

```
@browser.windows
```

You can switch to another window by handle, title, url, index or collection

```
@browser.window(title: 'My new window').use
@browser.windows.first.use
```

Comment: Hi titus, thank you for your reply. It was this , plus a registry key which i needed to add for IE 11. 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0. 

Sometimes it that easy.